# Is there a way to get grab content from ejs to node-js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a ejs page that has a bunch of inputs in a form. Is there a way to get those input from the ejs page and pass them back to the server? 
I know how to pass variables to ejs pages through the server, but is there a way to do the opposite? Basically, I'm asking if there is a way to pass from client to server.

Comment: Of course there is and there are lots of tutorials for working with forms and express all over the web as well as the documentation

Comment: I tried looking for it and couldn't find anything. I even tried looking for other stack overflow posts about this and also didn't find anything. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: This search link shows tons of results https://www.google.com/search?q=express+form+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a post api with express + body parser:

```
router.post('/myapi', (req, res) => {
  // Do some stuff with the req body data
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  otherStuff: req.body.stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thank You so much!

Comment: @RomanRoshchuk No problemo. I'd suggest taking a look at 'jsonwebtoken' for auth and 'bcryptjs' for hashing. Cheers!